# RabbitMQ doesn't start using launchd

Tags: macos, rabbitmq, launchd, launch-daemon

I use a MacPorts ecosystem and the `rabbitmq-server` port is really old and it doesn't work anymore. So I have installed `rabbitmq-server` on Mac OS X Sierra, using [Generic Unix release](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-generic-unix.html). It works.

RabbitMQ is installed under `/usr/local/rabbitmq_server-3.6.5/` and there are symlinks for all the executables under `/usr/local/sbin/`.

```
ls -al
total 40
drwxr-xr-x  7 root  wheel  238 Sep 24 19:50 .
drwxr-xr-x  8 root  wheel  272 Sep 24 19:30 ..
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   55 Sep 24 19:50 rabbitmq-defaults -> /usr/local/rabbitmq_server-3.6.5/sbin/rabbitmq-defaults
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   50 Sep 24 19:50 rabbitmq-env -> /usr/local/rabbitmq_server-3.6.5/sbin/rabbitmq-env
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   54 Sep 24 19:50 rabbitmq-plugins -> /usr/local/rabbitmq_server-3.6.5/sbin/rabbitmq-plugins
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   53 Sep 24 19:50 rabbitmq-server -> /usr/local/rabbitmq_server-3.6.5/sbin/rabbitmq-server
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   49 Sep 24 19:50 rabbitmqctl -> /usr/local/rabbitmq_server-3.6.5/sbin/rabbitmqctl
```

When I run the RabbitMQ server, everything works like expected:

```
sudo rabbitmq-server
Password:

          RabbitMQ 3.6.5. Copyright (C) 2007-2016 Pivotal Software, Inc.
##  ##      Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
##  ##
##########  Logs: /usr/local/rabbitmq_server-3.6.5/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@MacBookPro.log
######  ##        /usr/local/rabbitmq_server-3.6.5/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@MacBookPro-sasl.log
##########
          Starting broker...
completed with 6 plugins.
```

To start the daemon automatically I have created a file `com.rabbitmq.rabbitmq-server.plist` that I have placed under `/usr/local/etc/LaunchDaemons`. I have also created a symlink to this file in `/Library/LaunchDaemons`. The owner is `root` and the group is `wheel`.

```
ls -al
total 88
drwxr-xr-x  13 root  wheel   442 Sep 24 19:51 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 61 root  wheel  2074 Sep 23 14:33 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   103 Dec 11  2015 com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool.plist -> /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Resources/com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool.plist
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    63 Sep 24 19:16 com.rabbitmq.rabbitmq-server.plist -> /usr/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/com.rabbitmq.rabbitmq-server.plist
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    66 Sep 12 10:04 org.freedesktop.dbus-system.plist -> /opt/local/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.freedesktop.dbus-system.plist
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    76 Sep 23 16:40 org.macports.OpenSSH.plist -> /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.OpenSSH/org.macports.OpenSSH.plist
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    76 Sep 20 20:43 org.macports.apache2.plist -> /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.apache2/org.macports.apache2.plist
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    80 Sep 13 00:46 org.macports.memcached.plist -> /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.memcached/org.macports.memcached.plist
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    90 Sep 23 16:33 org.macports.mysql56-server.plist -> /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql56-server/org.macports.mysql56-server.plist
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    72 Sep 23 15:17 org.macports.redis.plist -> /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.redis/org.macports.redis.plist
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    74 Sep 23 15:19 org.macports.rsyncd.plist -> /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.rsyncd/org.macports.rsyncd.plist
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    72 Sep 12 18:00 org.macports.slapd.plist -> /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.slapd/org.macports.slapd.plist
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    84 May 25 03:58 org.macports.supervisord.plist -> /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.supervisord/org.macports.supervisord.plist
```

Here is the plist file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <true/>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.rabbitmq.rabbitmq-server</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/sbin/rabbitmq-server</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
  <dict>
    <key>PATH</key>
    <string>/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin</string>
  </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

When I try to load the plist file using

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.rabbitmq.rabbitmq-server.plist
```

I don't get any error, but the daemon doesn't start. I have even tried to add debug information to the plist, but the log doesn't show any error.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it wasn't easy but I have finally found a solution myself.

This is the final `com.rabbitmq.rabbitmq-server.plist` script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.rabbitmq.rabbitmq-server</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/opt/local/bin/daemondo</string>
    <string>--label=rabbitmq-server</string>
    <string>--start-cmd</string>
    <string>/usr/local/sbin/rabbitmq-server</string>
    <string>-u</string>
    <string>nobody</string>
    <string>;</string>
    <string>--pid=exec</string>
  </array>
  <key>Disabled</key><true/>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key><true/>
  <key>KeepAlive</key><true/>
  <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
  <dict>
    <key>HOME</key>
    <string>/usr/local/rabbitmq_server-3.6.5</string>
    <key>PATH</key>
    <string>/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/rabbitmq_server-3.6.5/sbin</string>
  </dict>
  <key>StandardOutPath</key>
  <string>/var/log/rabbit-launchd.log</string>
  <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/var/log/rabbit-launchd-error.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have used `daemondo` from MacPorts to run the `rabbitmq-server` executable. Than I have updated the `PATH` variable. Using the `StandardErrorPath` I have figured out that ErLang couldn't find the executable home dir: I got, in fact, this error:

```
erlexec: HOME must be set
```

So I have added `HOME` to the `EnvironmentVariables` section.

If you relay on MacPorts and you don't use Homebrew, you can use this script to run RabbitMQ server using `launchd` and installing the Generic Unix release.